# In cavity quantum electrodynamics why is $\langle \hat{a} \rangle$ called the cavity amplitude?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, cavity-qed

What is the physical meaning behind $\langle \hat{a} \rangle$ (where $\hat{a}$ is the annhilation operator)?

I was thinking that it represents $\sqrt{n}$ (where $n$ is the number of photons in the system) since $\hat{n} = \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}$ (where $\hat{n}$ is the number operator).

Why is $\langle \hat{a} \rangle$ referred to as the cavity amplitude in cavity quantum electrodynamics?

Answer (score 1):

The electric and the magnetic field operators can be constructed from the ladder-operators. The real part of the expectation value is proportional to the classical field amplitude, so I guess that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Much like the electromagnetic field in classical electrodynamics $\mathbf{E}$, the expectation value $\langle\hat{a}\rangle$ is a **complex number**. It thus corresponds to something like an amplitude, whereas the number operator expactation value $\langle\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}\rangle$ corresponds to something like the intensity.

The correspondence can also be formalized since in quantum electrodynamics, we have
$$\mathbf{E} \sim \hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger \,.$$

For details see any textbook on quantum optics or [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field) as an easily accessible source.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How would you physical interpret $\langle \hat{a} \rangle$?

Comment: @Nice1m80 Is the physical interpretation as an amplitude not sufficient?

Comment: I was just wondering if it had anything to do with the annhilation of the photons in the cavity. Since we are taking the expectation value of the annhilation operator. So I am wondering what does $\langle a \rangle$ represent in that sense?

Comment: @Nice1m80 I would suggest to try and compute the expectation value for some example states to get intuition. For a coherent state, you will find a close relation to the photon number. However, for Fock states this expectation value is zero. A general and concrete physical interpretation is therefore difficult (also since this expectation value is rarely measure directly in experiment).